# With the Horizon Walker ranger's Distant Strike feature, can you teleport prior to a bonus-action attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, actions, ranger, teleportation

At 11th level, the Horizon Walker Ranger gets the **Distant Strike** feature, which states:

> At 11th level, you gain the ability to pass between the planes in the blink of an eye. When you take the Attack action, you can teleport up to 10 feet before each attack to an unoccupied space you can see.

What's unclear is whether this is *only* for the Attack action attacks, or whether it's triggered as long as you take the Attack action. If the latter, does that mean you can teleport prior to a bonus-action attack? Or the attack granted from *haste*?

Answer (score 7):

### When is an attack the Attack action?

*Distant Strike* is pretty clear - it says **Attack action** with the capital A. It is not any action that allows the character to make an attack (such as *Green Flame Blade*, which includes an attack as part of the **Cast A Spell** action).

> At 11th level, you gain the ability to pass between the planes in the blink of an eye. When you take the Attack action, you can teleport up to 10 feet before each attack to an unoccupied space you can see.

The **Attack action** and the ability to teleport are part of the same sentence - "when" and "each" ties the two together. If you're not currently in the midst of the **Attack action**, you don't benefit from *Distant Strike*.

There are no hidden rules. If the ability were meant to work in conjunction with anything but the **Attack action**, it would say so. Perhaps something like "On a turn you take the Attack action..." or "each attack during your turn", but it doesn't use more permissive wording.

Take [*Reckless Attack*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#RecklessAttack) for example:

> When you make your first attack on your turn, you can decide to attack recklessly. Doing so gives you advantage on melee weapon attack rolls using Strength during this turn, but attack rolls against you have advantage until your next turn.

It has to be activated before the first attack and it specifically affects all melee weapon attacks: it doesn't require the **Attack action**. A Dual Wielding Fighter Barbarian could combine it with Action Surge, and all the attacks would benefit. Opportunity Attacks, however, would not - because it ends when the turn ends (the downside lasts longer).

### *Haste*? Yes.

Haste says:

> That action can be used only to take the **Attack** (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

*Haste* allows the **Attack action** (capital A), but has a special caveat. It is still the **Attack action**, so it meets the requirements of *Distant Strike*.

### Bonus action attacks? No.

I am unaware of any bonus action that allows a character to take the **Attack action** (again, capital A), just ones that allow the character to make an attack (lower-case).

If such a thing did exist, it would potentially allow for a Fighter to potentially attack twelve times in a round - regular **Attack action** and this hypothetical bonus "Attack" action for four each, plus Action Surge for another four.

Comment: Can you clarify that passing the gate of "take the Attack action" ends as soon as the Attack action ends and isn't ongoing past it?

Comment: @NautArch No problem. I didn't read the question as implying that part was in doubt.

Comment: That's on me! I'll try an edit, but basically that was the crux of it. However, I think citing the rules in cases where the gate continues has language like "until the end ofy our turn" or "until the start of your next turn" or something like that would probably close this out.

Comment: @NautArch Yeah, I've got an example in mind, I just need to get to someplace I can pull up DDB and get proper references. :)

Answer (score 0):

### It's implied that this feature can only be used for the attacks that are part of the Attack action.

The usage of the word "each" indicates this intent.

> **Distant Strike**: When you take the Attack action, you can teleport [...] before **each** attack.

At Level 11, the Ranger already has access to Extra Attack, so the authors of this feature likely added "each" to clarify that the Horizon Walker can use this feature for the attacks included in their Attack action.

If it had been the authors' intent for this to be used for *any* attack during a turn, then they would have called this out with specific verbiage in the text as is common in 5e. An example of this is the Way of the Four Elements Fangs of the Fire Snake feature (credit to @Medix2 for providing this example):

> **Fangs of the Fire Snake**: When you use the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 Ki point to cause tendrils of flame to stretch out from your fists and feet. Your reach with your unarmed strikes increases by 10 feet for that action, *as well as the rest of the turn*.

You'll notice that this specifically calls out the duration of this feature, something that is conspicuously missing from the text for Distant Strike.

### As for your follow-up questions...

Seeing as a *Haste* attack is simply a modified version of a regular Attack action, this feature *can*, however, be used for attacks made via Haste as well. Bonus action attacks, on the other hand, are not made with the Attack action, and therefore cannot benefit from this feature.

Comment: For somewhat of an example of a feature that applies beyond just the Attack action there is the Way of the Four Elements Monk's Fangs of the Fire Snake feature: "When you use the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 ki point to cause tendrils of flame to stretch out from your fists and feet. Your reach with your unarmed strikes increases by 10 feet *for that action, as well as the rest of the turn.*"

Comment: @Medix2 great example. If you're not planning on using it in an answer of your own, mind if I edit it into mine?

Comment: Go right ahead, I actually wrote up an answer and then realized it was incredibly similar to yours so I've deleted it

Comment: @Medix2 much appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

## Bonus Actions allow you to perform an Action

The rules for [Bonus Actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions) states:

> Various class features, spells, and other abilities let you take an additional action on your turn called a bonus action.

If a feature allows you to Attack as a Bonus Action, then you are performing the Attack action and can use the Distant Strike feature. However, at the moment there isn't any way to get a bonus action attack.

### Haste isn't a bonus action

[Haste](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) states you gain an "additional" action, not a bonus action:

> ... it gains an **additional action** on each of its turns. That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

If this additional action is used to take the Attack action, then you can use the Distant Strike feature.

### Two-weapon fighting isn't a bonus action

[Two-weapon fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) states:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, **you can use a bonus action to attack** with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand.

You can attack as a bonus action, but you do not take the attack action.

### Distant Strike's effect only applies to the action that triggers it

Distant strike reads:

> **When** you take the Attack action, you can teleport up to 10 feet before each attack to an unoccupied space you can see.

The choice of language "when" you attack, "each" attack, makes it clear that the feature only activates for that attacks within that attack action. If it was intended to last the entire turn/round/encounter/forever then it would say so.